# Connecting Visual Studio to multiple Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Simple Question, 
I have few Team Foundation Servers I'm working with. 
I want to be able to easily switch between them 
(a solution based approach - each solution will be managed at it's own TFS).

Is there an easy way to achieve this or do I have to reconfigure VS2013 each time from scratch ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it is possible from 
Home->another click on HOME-> Project and My Teams->connect to Team Projects-> Press on Servers button and you can Add another TFS server.

Comment: Just to add: first you need to go to Team Explorer